# Customise Sharepoint QuickLaunch menu per subsite page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, quicklaunch

Is there a way I can have a custom quick launch menu on a particular page on a MOSS subsite.

I have tried detaching the page layout on on the page this works fine and copys the master page layout code into the aspx file. But it does not copy the code for the Quick launch menu.

I know I can change the Quick Launch items per site but can I change this per page on a site?

Thanks
Nav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by using JQuery to hide the Quick launch panel. Rather than creating a new master page

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For this you need to create a new master page with different Quick launch. And go to your page and change its master page.